# How to have the enumerate label left aligned

Tags: enumerate, alignment

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 

\begin{center}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
 & \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} & \{1,4\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{3,4\} \\
x_1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
x_2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
x_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
x_4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{center}

\item Two.
\item Three.

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately the 1. just before the matrix is centered as well. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty hack:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  \hfill $\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
 & \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} & \{1,4\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{3,4\} \\
x_1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
x_2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
x_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
x_4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$\hfill\mbox{}

\item Two.
\item Three.

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution is to put the matrix inside a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{center}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
 & \{1,2\} & \{1,3\} & \{1,4\} & \{2,3\} & \{2,4\} & \{3,4\} \\
x_1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
x_2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
x_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
x_4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\item Two.
\item Three.

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]